# How do I get liquibase to skip table creation if it already exists with liquibase formatted sql?

Tags: testing, h2, liquibase

This is what I have

```
--preconditions onFail:CONTINUE
--preconditions not tableExists tableName:QRTZ_CALENDARS schemaName:dbo
CREATE TABLE dbo.QRTZ_CALENDARS (
 SCHED_NAME VARCHAR (120)  NOT NULL ,
 CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL ,
 CALENDAR IMAGE NOT NULL
) 
GO
```

Background. I'm using liquibase to setup a h2 database for test cases in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment "formatted SQL" changelogs only support the "SQL check" precondition.
Example:

```
--preconditions onFail:HALT onError:HALT
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

Info source (and updates): https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html

If more complicated preconditions are required -- one could try moving to a non-SQL Liquibase format, i.e. XML or JSON

Answer (score 34):

Add a pre-Condition to your changeset for example:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <tableExists tableName="Table_name"/>
    </not>
</preConditions>
<createTable tableName="Table_name" >
    <column name="column1" type="NUMBER(20,0)"/>
</createTable>
```

Comment: The question shows the use of the precondition. It doesn't do anything.